# ワードプレスで日本語ファイル名の画像が表示されない

Tags: php, wordpress

日本語ファイル名の画像が表示されないので
下記の記事などを参考にWP Multibyte Patchプラグインのインストール、画像のアップロードし直しなどしたのですが
まだ表示されません。
https://blog-blog.net/japanesefilename_imgupload/

ただファイルが日本語名でも表示されている画像もあります。
表示されている画像は下記のようにエンコードされています。
currentSrc: http://uploads/2020/02/%…3%82%B1%E3%82%A.png

ちなみに`<head>`タグの中で `<meta charset="UTF-8">`と設定しています。

どうしたら、エンコードして表示することができるのでしょうか？

Comment: 日本語名で表示できない、具体的なファイル名を教えてもらうことはできますか？

Comment: @keitaro_so こちらです！`uploads/2020/02/Q4.あなたにとって仕事のモチベーションは何ですか？（2つまでお選びください）-1024x819.png`

Comment: 妄想レベルっスけど HTML は UTF-8 配下ではあるもののファイルシステムへ渡すエンコーディングが CP932 ってことだと `SJIS ダメ文字` が原因なのかな。うまくいくファイル名もあると判断材料が増えるかも。

Comment: @774RR UTF-8でアップロードし直したら表示されました。ありがとうございました！